# Python Qt QToolbar overflow button edit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, toolbar, qtoolbar

I want to edit the overflow button of a python qt qtoolbar so that it doesn't closes automatically when I move my cursor of it. I want to click the overflow button again to close it

I am not an expert and I did not find anything about this topic

Comment: Subclass `QToolBar`, and just override `event()` as in the duplicated question, or do the same within an event filter for `Leave` event types.